# Adding stratified variable to a dataframe in R

Tags: r, random

I have some data that I want to split into 4 equal parts based on the group.

My dataframe looks like this:

| X | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 8 | 2 |
| 9 | 3 |
| 10 | 3 |
| 11 | 3 |
| 12 | 3 |
| 13 | 3 |
| 14 | 3 |
| 15 | 3 |
| 16 | 3 |

Now I thought about adding a thrid column to mark which data belong to which split, like this:

| X | Group | Split |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | 1 | 4 |
| 6 | 1 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 | 3 |
| 8 | 2 | 1 |
| 9 | 3 | 1 |
| 10 | 3 | 2 |
| 11 | 3 | 3 |
| 12 | 3 | 4 |
| 13 | 3 | 1 |
| 14 | 3 | 2 |
| 15 | 3 | 3 |
| 16 | 3 | 4 |

I don't need to actually split the dataset, because the data are videos and I just have to mark how (which person) has to watch them.

I know how I can generate random numbers, but I need them to be stratified to the group.

I know how I can get a stratified sample, but thats not I want, because I want to distribute ALL data (videos in this case) but in a stratified fashion.

Can you help me how to achieve this?

Thank you!

edit: I changed to example to unequally sized groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do these kind of stratified operations using `dplyr::group_by()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
    X = 1:12,
    Group = c(rep(1,4), rep(2,4), rep(3,4))
)

df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(Split = sample(seq_along(X), size = n(), replace = FALSE) %% 4 + 1) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Thank you. I see that my example wasn't good, because the size of every group isn't the same. Is there an (easy) way I can get the size of each group (in order to replace the "4" with "size")?

Comment: Yes, I’ve edited my answer to accommodate any / variable number of rows per group. You can get the size of each group using `dplyr::n()`, which I now pass to the `size` argument to `sample()`. You *could* then sample from `1:n()`… however `seq_along()` is generally safer in cases with unknown / variable n, because `1:n()` will fail if `n() == 0`.

Comment: I looked at your edited example and realized you still want 4 output groups, even if the number of rows in a group > 4. I’ve made one more edit to accommodate this, using modulo.